# OpenCV SVD returns different result than MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, svd

I am using SVD function to get values.
In my Opencv, I wrote

```
Mat w, u, vt;
SVD::compute(A, w, u, vt);
```

After compare the values against the MATLAB, it seems u and vt matrix does not match with what the MATLAB returns. The values actually match, but sometime, U(:1), and VT(:1) is negated from what OpenCV returns. Sometime, VT elements are negated and flipped. Although U*VT returns same value as MATLAB, U and VT itself is different than MATLAB (randomly) and I am not sure what is causing this. I am using OpenCV 2.4 and can you help me on how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the singular values are ordered differently, i.e. in `A = u w vt`, the diagonal matrix `w` (of singular values) has the entries ordered differently from MATLAB. In MATLAB the singular values are ordered in decreasing order on the main diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Singular Value Decomposition is only defined up to a sign; the signs of U and V are arbitrary, and if they are different between MATLAB and OpenCV that does not indicate a problem.